# Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web not compatible with netcoreapp

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

Full problem text:

```
Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web 2.4.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)
Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web 2.4.0 supports:
    - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
    - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
```

So when I try to access Live Metrics Stream in Azure I get the message:
**Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK**
and the following step-by-step guide to getting it:

- Make a copy of ApplicationInsights.config if you customized ApplicationInsights.config.
- In Solution Explorer, right-click your project and choose Manage NuGet packages.
- Select Browse.
- Search for Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web, select it and choose Install/Update. You need version 2.2.0 (or later).
- Reinstate any customizations you made to ApplicationInsights.config. Most of the changes you'll see when you compare the files are because we removed some modules and made others parameterizable.
- Rebuild your solution.

(I haven't customized no ApplicationInsights.config so started at 2, got the error after 4)

So I'm not entirely sure what the problem here is, on thing I guess from the problem text is that ApplicationInsights.Web works with .NETFramework and not with .NETCoreApp. In that case my question would be:

What's the ApplicationInsights.Web alternative for .NETCoreApp? Plus, why does Azure recommend this step-by-step guide to me? Can't they see that I'm running a .NETCoreApp?

In case it's relevant:
I have student access to Visual Studio and Azure through something called Microsoft Imagine.

Answer (score 2):

The guide is for classic MVC, not MVC Core.

For ASP.NET Core, you should be able to add App Insights with the connected service in Visual Studio: https://ppolyzos.com/2017/03/07/add-application-insights-in-a-net-core-app-using-vs-2017-and-connected-services/

> To add one of the supported connected services you can right-click on
>   your Project and select Add Connected Service. Select Application
>   Insights and, from the next dialog, click on the Start Free button to
>   start the registration of Application Insights in your app.
>   Then, connect your Microsoft Azure account, choose your subscription
>   and resource group and, at the bottom, select whether you want app
>   insights to continue collecting data beyond 1 GB/month or not, and
>   click on Register. A popup will appear displaying the progress of App
>   Insights registration process.

Also, the package that the connected service installs is: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/